# PreviewPageCountType.Final vs PreviewPageCountType.Intermediate

Tags: printing, windows-runtime

what is the difference in the behavior of the two values of the [PreviewPageCountType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.printing.previewpagecounttype%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreviewPageCountType` is used in `PrintDocument` method [SetPreviewPageCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702151.aspx) when your application tells Windows how many pages your can and/or want to show on the preview dialog.

In general, preparing print pages might take significant time, while Win Store Application UI is supposed to be very responsive and shouldn't wait more than necessary to respond to user requests.

For a developer, that means that you probably want to prepare preview pages in a background task. By the time preview flyout dialog needs to show the first page(s) to the user, that task might be only half-done and the number of total pages is yet unknown.

To remedy that, when `PrintDocument.Paginate` event is processed, you can call `SetPreviewPageCount` with a number of pages, say N, that are ready to be previewed. You tell Windows that it's not the final amount by `PreviewPageCountType.Intermediate`. Print preview dialog will hence allow user to see pages 1..N of N.

Once the application knows the exact number of pages, M, it makes another call with `PreviewPageCountType.Final` and Windows updates preview dialog,  allowing user to see pages 1..M of M.

You can actually do more intermediate updates, and the user will see an increasing number of available preview pages on the preview flyout:

```
printDocument.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, async () =>
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 300; i++)
    {
        printDocument.SetPreviewPageCount(i, PreviewPageCountType.Intermediate);
        await Task.Delay(50); // Simulate page generation delay
    }
    printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(300, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
});
```

Now, to tell the truth, as of now my tests show no real difference between `Intermediate` and `Final`. However, it's still a good idea to follow the expected pattern, in case future changes make it more strict.

Comment: Official response of Microsoft support : When you make the call to SetPreviewPageCount during print preview, passing PreviewPageCountType.Intermediate allows the app to show the first page in preview while it calculates the rest of the pages. Once everything is laid out (all pages are shown in print preview) and the actual page count is known, you pass PreviewPageCountType.Final to SetPreviewPageCount. What happens then is that SetJobPageCount is called with the total number of pages to be printed.